# Bluetooth speaker is connected, but not listed as output device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

I am trying to use a Google Mini as a bluetooth speaker. I can successfully pair, trust and connect the speaker via Bluez. However, it does not show as an available audio device, which means I cannot select it as my audio output.

The issue is device specific because my headset works perfectly. On top of that, my laptop (also running Ubuntu 23.10) connects flawlessly to the device. I would highly appreciate any help in figuring out why it works on my laptop but not on my PC.
My guess is conflicting audio services (Pipewire, Wireplumber, Pulseaudio) but I do not have enough knowledge to figure out on my own.

Any help is highly appreciated!

TIA

EDIT:
The bluetooth status when connecting and pairing the device

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-12-03 14:18:21 CET; 4h 13min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1075 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38334)
     Memory: 2.5M
        CPU: 70ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1075 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

dec 03 14:46:05 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
dec 03 14:46:05 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
dec 03 14:46:05 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
dec 03 14:46:05 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
dec 03 18:30:00 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:register_remote_sep() Unable to get remote sep codec
dec 03 18:30:00 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:register_remote_sep() Unable to get remote sep codec
dec 03 18:30:00 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:a2dp_select_capabilities() Unable to select SEP
dec 03 18:30:07 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:load_remote_sep() Unable to load LastUsed: rseid 1 not found
dec 03 18:30:07 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.19 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/source/3
dec 03 18:30:09 Northy bluetoothd[1075]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() avrcp-controller profile connect failed for F0:EF:86:70:4D:35: Operation already in progress
```